# c# Create Computer in Active Directory - Primary group issue

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm having issues creating computers via LDAP in C#:

The following is my code:

C#

```
string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ldapPath;

DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix, GlobalVar.adUser, GlobalVar.adUserPassword);

DirectoryEntry newComputer = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + computerName, "computer");
newComputer.Properties["samaccountname"].Value = computerName;
newComputer.Properties["dnshostname"].Value = computerName + ".[privacy].[domain].[here]";
newComputer.Properties["description"].Value = GlobalVar.adUser;
newComputer.Properties["location"].Value = "IT";
```

This works flawlessly with one exception: the computer is created in the correct folder. However the primary group is "Domain Users" instead of "Domain computers" when I create a computer directly in AD, the computer is automatically assigned the primary group "Domain Computers"

The result is that I cannot add the computer to the domain without editing it manually in ad.

Any solutions?

Best Regards,

Julian

Comment: Are you using .net 3.5 or above?

Comment: I do use .Net 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to do this...

LDAPusername = username with permissions to edit LDAP.

Pass the computername once it's created, then pass the group.

Sorry if this isn't perfect, this is my vb.net code I converted.

```
//The following code changes the principal group of an existing computer
PrincipalContext pc1 = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
    "subdomain.domain.com",
    LDAPusername,
    LDAPpassword
);
dynamic cp = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc1, "computername");
dynamic computer = (DirectoryEntry)cp.GetUnderlyingObject();
// distinguishedname = "CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
string @group = "groupdistinguishedname";
DirectoryEntry groupdirentry = new DirectoryEntry(
    "LDAP://" + @group,
    LDAPusername,
    LDAPpassword
);
groupdirentry.Invoke("Add", new object[] { computer.Path });
groupdirentry.CommitChanges();
groupdirentry.Invoke(
    "GetInfoEx",
    new object[] {
        new object[] { "primaryGroupToken" },
        0
    }
);
object primaryGroupToken = groupdirentry.Invoke(
    "Get",
    new object[] { "primaryGroupToken" }
);
computer.Invoke(
    "Put",
    new object[] {"primaryGroupID",primaryGroupToken}
);
computer.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you tony, nice code there. unfortunately I dont have permissions to add the computer to the group. is there a possibility to create the computer inside the group already?

I encountered the following behavior in ad:
when i do `rightclick >  new > computer` it is created in domain computers.

when i create the computer with my tool the principal group is "Domain Users". When I try to change it in AD afterwards i get the error "access denied"

Comment: So you get an error changing the principal group, or you get an error changing the principal group specifically do domain computers?

Comment: I get an error changing the pricipal group specifically to Domain computer, That why I ask for a way to create the computer already with the Domain Computers primary group

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the primaryGroupId to 515 I believe (Domain Computers)

```
newComputer.Properties["primaryGroupId"].Value = 515
```

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your comment, I tried this already. I am getting the following error message:

"The Server is unwilling to process the request."

may this be a permissions issue? If so, i could not understand why I can create computers with the same delegate account directly in AD.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was brought here initially after searching the web. Found the solution [here](https://rzander.azurewebsites.net/creating-active-directory-computer-objects-with-c/).

> To get a "valid" computer object, you have to set the attribute userAccountControl to 0x1020 = (PASSWD_NOTREQD | WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT) and it's also recommended to set the sAMAccountName to the computername (in uppercase) followed by a '$' (same as if you create the object from the Management Console).

```
newComputer.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 0x1020;
```

This resolved the issue for me.